# OPENMP reproducibility with 1 or n threads

Tags: multithreading, openmp, locks

I am working on to parallelize small part of the code which has do loops and the call subroutines. But results are not consistant with 1 thread or 2 threads.

Is it like for this type of programs we have to use locks?

```
!$OMP parallel private(kk,j,i,k1,j1,i1,k2,j2,i2,ic,icm,xx,yy,ydatm),shared(undef,lt,ln,nd,xd,tgrd,ndaym)
 thread_id   = OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
 num_threads = OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS()
 if(thread_id.eq.0) thread_id=thread_id+1
 start_no    = (thread_id * ndaym / num_threads);
 end_no      = ((thread_id + 1) * ndaym / num_threads);
 xx(:)=undef
 yy(:,:)=undef 

!$OMP DO 
 DO kk=start_no,end_no

  do j=1,nlat
   do i=1,nlon
    ic=0
    do k1=kk-nd,kk+nd
     k2=k1
     if(k2.lt.1)k2=1
     if(k2.gt.ndaym)k2=ndaym
     do j1=j-lt,j+lt
      j2=j1
      if(j2.lt.1)j2=1
      if(j2.gt.nlat)j2=nlat
      do i1=i-ln,i+ln
       i2=i1
       if(i2.lt.1)i2=1
       if(i2.gt.nlon)i2=i2-nlon
       ic=ic+1
       yy(ic,:)=xdatm(i2,j2,k2,:)
       yya(:) = yy(ic,:)
       call funcmean(yya,xx(ic),1,nmem,nmem,undef)
       if(k1.eq.kk.and.j1.eq.j.and.i1.eq.i) then
         icm=ic
         call funcsd(yya,1,nmem,nmem,undef,xx(ic),xd)
       endif
      enddo  ! for i1       
     enddo   ! for j1
    enddo   ! for k1
   call funcens(xx,yy,tgrd,nmem,icm,undef,dist)
    ydatm(i,j,kk,:)= dist(:)
  enddo !for nlon
 enddo ! for nlat   
 ENDDO !kk

!$OMP end do
deallocate(xx,yy)
!$OMP end parallel
```

Can anyone give some clues?

Comment: It looks to me as if you are trying to calculate each thread's share of the outer do loop iterations, with all that the fiddling around to calculate `start_no` and `end_no`.  If so you've rather missed one of the main points about OpenMP which is that the compiler does that for you.  There are plenty of good examples on the 'net, even here on SO, to show you the usual super-structure of a parallelised do loop in Fortran+OpenMP.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether the rest of the code is correct (I actually didn't even try to read it TBH) but the beginning is clearly wrong:

```
!$OMP parallel private(kk,j,i,k1,j1,i1,k2,j2,i2,ic,icm,xx,yy,ydatm),shared(undef,lt,ln,nd,xd,tgrd,ndaym)
 thread_id   = OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
 num_threads = OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS()
 if(thread_id.eq.0) thread_id=thread_id+1
 start_no    = (thread_id * ndaym / num_threads);
 end_no      = ((thread_id + 1) * ndaym / num_threads);
```

I'll try to summarise what I found wrong in just this snippet:

- The variables `thread_id`, `num_threads`, `start_no` and `end_no` are not declared `private`. They are therefore implicitly `shared` which is obviously very wrong. To avoid such basic pitfall, I would highly encourage you to use a `default(none)` clause in your `!$omp parallel` directive. This will definitely spare you a lot of headaches.
- `if(thread_id.eq.0) thread_id=thread_id+1`: Ok so assuming that `thread_id` had been (as it should have) declared `private`. After that, 2 different threads (threads #0 and #1) will both have the same value for `thread_id` which is 1. What sense does that make?
- Then `start_no` and `end_no` (even once declared `private`) are computed using a `thread_id` value which is bogus for thread #0.

Try fixing these first and see what it gives.

An extra glance at the rest of the code makes me suspect that `deallocate(xx,yy)` is likely to be an issue too: unless the allocation was done in the parallel region (which doesn't look to be the case here, but still is possible), the deallocation should be move outside of it.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark fair enough, I hadn't think about automatic allocation here. But as you pointed out, the syntax seems bogus anyway.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark at second thought, even assuming correct automatic allocation syntax, how could `undef` be used for this purpose where `xx` seems to be 1D and `yy` to be 2D? At least one of the two assignments wouldn't work, would it?